# Downloaded webpage looks different than the original webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am thinking of downloading [cplusplus.com's C library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/) by using Python. I want to download it completely and then convert it into a linked document such as Python documentation. This is my initial attempt at downloading the front page.

```
#! python3
import urllib.request

filehandle = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/')

with open('test.html', 'w+b') as f:
    for line in filehandle:
        f.write(line)

filehandle.close()
```

The front page is being downloaded correctly but its look is quite different than in the original webpage. By different look I mean that the nice looking formatting on the original webpage is gone after I ran the script to download the webpage.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: [web-scraping] isn't downloading a webpage so you can view it offline, it's the process of extracting information from a page that's not available through an API...

Comment: Use `wget` with `-p` parameter.

Comment: @Wooble I am new to this and its definition about extracting data seemed to apply as I am extracting all of the data i.e. the complete webpage. If it is wrong by definition then I'll remove it. I don't know why wikipedia placed retrieving a webpage under web scraping. See for yourself [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). Search for HTTP programming.

Comment: @FlashThunder Actually I wanted to do it using Python. For learning purposes. But thanks for the suggestion. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Display the source code of your page. You will find the `<link...` with the css file. You can download it manually, or you can use Python to download it. However, you have to extract the URL of the CSS file somehow. The link has `type="text/css"`. To do it automatically, you have to parse the content of the page and search for the link and its URL. This is what the suggested `wget` also does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because your scraped version doesn't include the Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) linked to by the page. It also won't include any images or javascript linked to either. If you want to obtain the linked files, you'll have to parse the source code you scrape for them.

Comment: So I'll have to look at `urllib.parse`? Not asking for the code but I am a newbie so any hints at which libraries to look at would be really helpful.

Comment: `urllib.parse` relates to parsing URLs - not the content of the pages at the URL, but the URL itself. This isn't what you're trying to do. The simplest solution will likely be to write a regex (regular expression) search for all `<style>` tags and get the CSS URLs from them.

Comment: Just to be clear I'll repeat what I understood. I need to look for all <style> tags using `re`, get CSS URLs and then add them to my output html file. Correct?

Comment: Almost - you have to download them separately, and you may have to rewrite the links in the style sheets to point to a new location. However, you're doing this for a single website, right? It is likely to have a finite number of stylesheets, which will be the same for every page. You may be able to simply download them all manually.

Comment: I am doing this for a single website and I plan to rewrite the links for making it like the Python documentation. I know I am asking for many clarifications but I'll ask for at least one more. After downloading them separately I'll have to add them to the downloaded webpage. Correct this time?

Comment: No. The CSS files are LINKED from the webpage (not contained within it), and will be linked from the downloaded webpage. For example, cplusplus.com comtains the following line: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/v315/main.css">` This means that there is a file located at /v315/main.css with style information. You simply have to put that file in the same location in your local version to be able to access it (that's relative to the webpage).

Also, I misspoke earlier; it's a `<link>` tag, not a `<style>` tag. `<style>` tags are for CSS that's embedded in the page.